# Update view after http subscribe, angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get('/api_admin/user').subscribe(data => {
        // Read the result field from the JSON response.
        this.results = data;

    });
}
```

view:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let project of results.name"></li>
</ul>
```

Gives console error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Do I somehow need to "tell" the view that a value has arrived?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is `undefined`, while it wants to use in the template. Or you can set the default value for the `results` or you can use `ngIf` to show that part only when the data was arrived.

Set default value for `results`

```
results: any = { name: [] };
```

or use `ngIf`

```
<ul *ngIf="results">
  <li *ngFor="let project of results.name"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah. Works. However (bit offtopic maybe). My view show this: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. Do I need to convert it somehow?

Comment: use json pipe :-)

Comment: {{project | json }}

Comment: I think you print `project` so it shows `[object Object]`, so `project` is an object.Probably you need to access its property

Answer (score 0):

Your results is undefined.

Initiate your variable in typescript file

```
public results = {
    name: []
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use safe **navigation operator(?)** to handle null and undefined in Angular View

```
 <ul>
  <li *ngFor="let project of results?.name"></li>
</ul>
```